# Where do I edit the helm chart if I want to change the port used by alertmanager-operated service in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I am installing the below helm package on my K8s cluster

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/releases/tag/kube-prometheus-stack-21.0.0

I've got it locally and when I deploy it creates everything including a service called alertmanager-operated. Its listening on TCP port 9093 and I need to change this. I dont see where this can be configured in the values.yaml or anywhere else in the package

Comment: Why do you need to change it ? 9093 is the usual API/GUI port of alertmanager.

Comment: Its causing an issue with another app that is listening on that port ( its a long story) If i change the port manually everything works fine but it reverts back after a while so i need a way of changing permanently

Answer (score 2):

It's [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/b25f5a532f26e28852d5e3b125c902428f521adf/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L301). Your values.yaml can have:

```
...
alertmanager:
  service:
    port: <your port #>
```

Follow-up on your comment `... cant tell how the alertmanager-operated service gets created and how to configure it`

[Here's](https://www.vmware.com/topics/glossary/content/kubernetes-services) a good source for quick understanding of various k8s services. For greater configure details checkout the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Set the values according to your need and k8s will create the service for you when you apply the chart.

Comment: That only controls the port used by the monitoring-alertmanager service (I've sucessfully changed that one from the values.yaml). I actually cant tell how the alertmanager-operated service gets created and how to configure it

NAME                                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
alertmanager-operated                 ClusterIP   None           <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   47m
monitoring-alertmanager               ClusterIP   10.0.74.132    <none>        8093/TCP                     47m

Comment: Are you really asking how to expose alert manager outside of cluster?

Comment: no i just need to change it to any other port. Its causing an issue with another app that is listening on that port ( its a long story) If i change the port manually everything works fine but it reverts back after a while so i need a way of changing permanaently . t

Comment: To be clear, you have another container running in the **same** alertmanager pod which open the same port 9093?

Comment: no its an app running in my cluster that talks to a kafka cluster on port 9093. For whatever reason it cant talk to kafka on 9093 when alertmanager-operated service is listening on port 9093. It errors like below
 Connection to node 1003 (/172.18.29.6:9093) terminated during authentication. Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.","[Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1003 (/172.18.29.6:9093) terminated

Comment: You aware that `kubectl get svc alertmanager-operated -n monitoring` actually return CLUSTER-IP `None`. This means `when alertmanager-operated service is listening on port 9093` is not true. This is a headless service that doesn't have an IP by itself. The error said `...Connection to node 1003 (/172.18.29.6:9093)`, can you do a `kubectl get svc,pod -n <prometheus namespace>` and see if `172.18.29.6` was assigned to any of the Prometheus app? If you do, can you tell which Prometheus app is that. If you don't, can you find out which pod is assigned with this IP in your cluster.